# Non linear regression: Outlier sensitive loss function

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, loss-function, non-linear-regression

I'm trying to come up with a non-linear regression deep learning model to predict the far field of a given nanostructure.

The far-field spectrum is highly non-linear and it could have several resonance points (sudden increase in the field). See the graph below.

My DNN consists of 3 convolution layers followed by 4 dense layers to address non-linearity.

However, I would like to have a loss function which is more sensitive to outliers, so I could find the exact points where resonance occurs.

Till now, I have used quite a few loss functions and Huber loss performs best in terms of the settled final loss (0.0101), despite being less sensitive to outliers. The graph below shows the actual and predicted spectra.

Actual and predicted spectra:
[image]

I know mean squared error is sensitive to outliers but in this case, the settled loss (0.0198) is higher than the previous case.

What loss function is most sensitive to outliers specifically in not linear regression. If you could propose a custom loss function for this problem, that would also be fine.

Comment: You can generally use [Lp-norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#Lp_spaces), the higher the value of p the more sensitive to "outliers". However I'm not sure how this would help your network converge. The plot shows that the fit is not really good and also MSE does measure this. I suspect it's rather your network architecture that is not suitable to represent the problem in question. Also I don't see why you would use conv layers for that type of problem (because of the "similarity" of the two resonance lines?).

Comment: Well I did try writing my own code for L4 norm (I guess there is no in built function for L4 norm in tensorflow, is there?), and the loss doesn't seem to settle. And it runs very slowly. Answering your question, I used conv layers here because the nanostructures are 64x64 images, where 3 materials being mixed in a symmetric manner (think of a 64x64 image with symmetry, and with only 3 colours).  And if I train the above neural network for like 10000 epochs, the train loss comes down to as low as 0.002, overfitting obviously. Does this mean I can solve the problem using this NN architecture?

Comment: I see. Since it doesn't work with L2 loss I didn't expect it to work with Lp loss either (L2 loss already measures these deviations). Having a small training loss of 0.002 is not bad as long as the validation loss comes down to the same magnitude. Does it? In case that you don't succeed in fitting that spectra you could try to modify your network architecture (deeper, wider, different activation functions, etc) or instead of predicting the full spectrum, instead you could predict the position and amplitude of resonance points (given that the count is fixed, otherwise use an upper limit maybe).